# Assign Workflow Tasks to Queue or Public Group

Tags: workflow, tasks, public-group, queue

How to assign the workflow task to group of users(Public group or Queue).I see this feature is not available in salesforce.Here are the idea exchange links for  [Queue](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007HC0AAM) and [Public Group](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l91fAAA)

Is it possible with triggers

Any Workaround for this?

Comment: Must it be the same task or everyone could have their own instance/clone of the task?

Comment: @zokito Its already possible to assign the same task to multiple users. That's been delivered. First to complete, then satisfies the workflow requirement. However, that doesn't tell the others who's picking up responsibility for the task until after its completed. Having the Task go to a "key" person who then either reassigns it or clones it to a queue for assignment would seem to be the only potential workaround.

Comment: @crmprogdev is it now possible to assign task to a queue? And related to the question you could simulate queues with a custom picklist on task. However that would also require a "key" person to have the task initially assigned to.

Comment: No, its not yet possible to assign them directly to a queue. There still needs to be a "key" person the task goes to first regardless of how to handle it.